# Hiding folder in the URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I change my URL from showing: `www.example.com/p/tools` to just `www.example.com/tools`?

I've tried to play around with the .htaccess a little bit, but unfortunately couldn't make it work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do share your htaccess Rule file in your question thank you

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for your kindness. I just uploaded that right away! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^p/(.*)/?$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hmm, i mean. The /p is gone now, but i have another problem. The URL now turns to: ```https://www.example.com/public_html/tools``` and gives me a "404 Not Found" error :/

Comment: @Berkanktk, I honestly thought about it, so for non existing files and directories to which file(index.php OR index.html) you want it to rewrite? If you can let me know this one I can fix it, cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i am not sure i understand what you mean by that. I have a html.index though. If that helps?

Comment: @Berkanktk, you are getting 404 because that page/directory doesn't exist, that's why I asked if a page is non existing then to which file it should point out in backend?

Comment: Thats weird, because it does exist? And index.html should be fine

Comment: @RavinderSingh15 So could you possibly help me, or? :/

Comment: @Berkanktk, sorry I was sleeping when you messaged me, without seeing you system I am trying to help you. So you need to give complete information and please try to response faster on comments too(whenever you are online). Ok please do let me know what is path of your files and what is path of you htaccess file? Thank you

Comment: Yea sorry it's 3 AM i Denmark right now, so soon it will be my turn :p. 
Okay so here it is, all of them: [Root directory](https://gyazo.com/50ed0eece6019fde81015b2de0f7ed8b), [p](https://gyazo.com/d0481c5cf3ef61ca70d41d42fc788e3d) and [images](https://gyazo.com/3f93b2c57fd86dee98affe2ec82964b9)

Comment: @Berkanktk, hey buddy please take rest now and ping me in next 4 to 5 hours after completing your sleep we can work on this one and I can try my best to help you. Please take rest  cheers

Comment: @RavinderSingh15, i made that post because i couldn't enter my pages. So i just wanted to step a little back and now solve the other issue with you. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229593/discussion-between-berkanktk-and-ravindersingh13).